# Python PropertyMock side effect with AttributeError and ValueError

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to mock a property of a class (@property decorator) and have bumped into this incorrect behaviour:

```
 >>> from mock import MagicMock, PropertyMock
 >>> m = MagicMock()
 >>> type(m).p = PropertyMock(side_effect=AttributeError)
 >>> m.p
 <MagicMock name='mock.p' id='63150736'>
```

The correct behaviour is this:

```
 >>> from mock import MagicMock, PropertyMock
 >>> m = MagicMock()
 >>> type(m).p = PropertyMock(side_effect=ValueError)
 >>> m.p
Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
ValueError
```

I cannot fathom why setting a different exception is giving me different results.  The expected result in both cases is that the exception should be raised!  So, the In[4] line should raise an `AttributeError`.  It does not.

*Anyone care to enlighten me?*

**Addendum**: The property I am trying to check does some clever checking to see if the value passed is sane.  If said value is not sane, it returns AttributeError as I understand that this is the correct exception in Python.  So, I need to check the code that uses the property for failure as well as success.  Thus, using a MagicMock to mock the property and raise said exception. A trivial example would be:

```
@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    if value < 0:
         raise AttributeError("Value cannot be negative!")
    self._x = value
```

Comment: You get the error the second time becaue you make m.p's side effect different from AttributeError by calling PropertyMock again (I'm not sure how and why). You can change the side effect without error like this: m.p.side_effect = ValueError

Comment: @kren470: Ah, sorry my question was unclear.  The second behaviour is correct.  The first one is not.  I expect an exception to be raised in both cases.  Question edited.

Comment: Same behaviour for me. I've submitted a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/mock/issues/detail?id=219

Comment: @AlexHammel: Thanks for that!  I'll keep an eye on that bug.

Comment: @Sardathrion No problem! I expect that the problem is that there's some kind of deep magic in the Mock class that catches AttributeErrors. We'll see what the devs say on the bug report, but it might be impractical to work around that using PropertyMock. There should definitely be a way to have a Mock raise an AttributeError, though. Might have to wait a few versions.

Comment: Pretty sure this intended and not a bug.  If you check the docs you'll see that Mocks by default catch and override AttributeError and return a Mock object instead.  That's how their working under the hood.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I've just had the same problem and found this question. Also the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/mock/issues/detail?id=219) submitted almost two years ago didn't seem to get any attention, so I thought I'll share the solution I found just in case anybody else will have this problem.

So, as stated `PropertyMock` doesn't work with `AttributeError` set as a `side_effect`. The workaround is to create a simple `Mock` with a `spec` attribute set to an empty `list` like this:

```
>>> from mock import Mock
>>> m = Mock(spec=[])
>>> m.p
Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
AttributeError
```

As stated in the [docs](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock):

> spec: This can be either a list of strings or an existing object (a class or instance) that acts as the specification for the mock object. If you pass in an object then a list of strings is formed by calling dir on the object (excluding unsupported magic attributes and methods). **Accessing any attribute not in this list will raise an AttributeError.**

Comment: Question might be old, but the answer is spot on. Thanks!

Comment: Except if you want the AttributeError message to be `"Value cannot be negative!"` you are out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Er, hold the phone. Does this cover your use case?

```
>>> import mock
>>> m = mock.MagicMock()
>>> m.p
<MagicMock name='mock.p' id='139756843423248'>
>>> del m.p #!
>>> m.p
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/home/ahammel/bin/python/mock-1.0.1-py2.6.egg/mock.py", line 664, in __getattr__
         raise AttributeError(name)
     AttributeError: p
```

I stumbled across that in [the docs](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#deleting-attributes) while looking for something entirely different.

Comment: No, it does not.  I'll expand the question.