# How can I mock a property to raise an exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

I'm using MagicMock with Python 2.7 to mock objects. One of the classes that I'm mocking has properties, one of which can raise a `TypeError` in some cases.

I would like to mock that behavior, but I can't figure out how:

- `del my_mock.my_property` will cause an `AttributeError` if `my_property` is accessed, but I need a `TypeError`.
- `my_mock.my_property = MagicMock(side_effect=TypeError)` causes a `TypeError` when `my_property` is *called*, but not when it's merely accessed.

How would I do that?

Comment: Just an idea: 2nd option + `my_mock.my_property = property(my_mock.my_property)`

Comment: Maybe make the property a class that defines a [```__delattr__```](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delattr__) method which changes its behavior when deleted.

Comment: Our maybe it's more accurate to say, define a ```__delattr__``` method for the mock object that will change the behavior of the property when it is deleted.

Comment: Our make the property a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) that does something similar when deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `PropertyMock` for this purpose:

```
import mock

class A(object):

    @property
    def prop(self):
        pass

a = A()
type(a).prop = mock.PropertyMock(side_effect=TypeError)
```

If you now access `a.prop` it'll raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: That looks like what I need, I'll check on Monday. Can I set that on a MagicMock instance as well?

Comment: This is fine, except if you want to raise an AttributeError with a custom message, `side_effect=AttributeError('something')`.  Then the side_effect is completely ignored.

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236123/python-propertymock-side-effect-with-attributeerror-and-valueerror